# How to set a test name using gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

How can I dynamically set names of google test cases using C++?
For example, I have a L2 switch with user-defined number of ports and I want to test every one with google test.

```
class VLAN : public ::testing::Test {};

TEST(VLAN, dot1qPortIngressFiltering_Port1_Min) {
    snmp.set("Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qPortIngressFiltering.1", Integer32(1));
    auto result = snmp.get("Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qPortIngressFiltering.1");
    auto res = std::get<Integer32>(result);
    ASSERT_EQ(res, Integer32(1));
}
```

Of course, I could manually copy-paste this case simply by changing one digit:`dot1qPortIngressFiltering_Port1_Min, dot1qPortIngressFiltering_Port2_Min, dot1qPortIngressFiltering_Port3_Min ...` but I don't even know the possible number of ports.

I've tried to pass test name constructed as a string, but it looks like `TEST()` doesn't accept string as the second parameter. I know we can get the test name with `test_info->name(), test_info->test_case_name());` but how can we set it?

Comment: How do you obtain the number of ports?

Comment: @AndyG it's user-defined. App reads .ini file and gets this information.

Comment: Okay, so probably we can't do anything using the google test macros... all that is code generation done at compile time, and you don't know the number of ports until run-time. We cannot, therefore, write individual tests for each port, but perhaps a single test that can loop through the ports.... unless you want to write a separate program that can read the .ini file and generate google test code to then be compiled and run afterwards.

Comment: @AndyG sounds right. I'd be better iterating through ports in a single test-case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Parameterized Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests) from googletest.

To create a parameterized test, the fixture class must derived from TestWithParam.

```
class VLAN : public TestWithParam<PortCase> {};
```

The parameter type is `PortCase`:

```
struct PortCase {
  int portNumber;
  std::string portName;
  PortCase(int portNumber, std::string portName) : 
          portNumber(portNumber), portName(portName) {}
}
```

Now we can write the real test (notice the TEST_P):

```
TEST_P(VLAN, dot1qPortIngressFiltering_Port1_Min) {
  PortCase input = GetParam();
  snmp.set(input.portName, Integer32(input.portNumber));
  auto result = snmp.get(input.portName);
  auto res = std::get<Integer32>(result);
  ASSERT_EQ(res, Integer32(input.portNumber));
}  

PortCase ports[] = {
  PortCase("Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qPortIngressFiltering.1", 1);
  PortCase("Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qPortIngressFiltering.2", 2);
  PortCase("Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qPortIngressFiltering.3", 3);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(PortTests, VLAN, ValuesIn(ports));
```

This should solve the question and is maybe a little bit prettier than lopping through the ports :-)